# Using query as PHP variable in another query

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a site where you can make posts and read post and now I am writing some code to filter these posts (like sort by 'new' or 'most liked')

I have this as query:

```
$search_query="SELECT Posts.user, Posts.title, Games.name, 
Posts.text, Posts.time, Posts.attachement
FROM Posts 
INNER JOIN Games ON Posts.game = Games.id 
WHERE Posts.game = '$game'
AND tag = '$tag' AND subtag = '$subtag'"
or die("The search_query on the database has failed!");
```

The normal $search_query works fine.
Now I want to extend this query if the user wants to sort the posts, for example posts of last week, day etc.:

```
if(!empty($_POST['time']))
{
    $search_query= "SELECT * FROM $search_query 
    WHERE time < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL $time)";
}
```

But this query doesn't work, cause I get this error:

```
mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in
```

I have read that this means that there is error in the query.
Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: `bool` means the query failed. Use error reporting to see what is happening. Also parameterize your query, this is injectable. Also `or die` will never occur because you are only assigning a variable there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is simply add the additional clauses to the existing WHERE

```
if(!empty($_POST['time']))
{
    $search_query .= " AND time < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL $time)";
}
```

> PS the `or die()` on here makes no sense as you are only putting text into a string variable, not executing it.

```
$search_query="SELECT Posts.user, Posts.title, Games.name, 
Posts.text, Posts.time, Posts.attachement
FROM Posts 
INNER JOIN Games ON Posts.game = Games.id 
WHERE Posts.game = '$game'
AND tag = '$tag' AND subtag = '$subtag'"
or die("The search_query on the database has failed!");
```